# match the content of vim register

Tags: regex, vim

i have a piece of code like this

```
int a=8;
cout<<"a is :"<<a<<endl;     // show what is the value of a
a=a*a;
string b="ice";              // b is ice
const char* c=b.c_str();
```

this code repeats at many places in exact same way. I want to find all the occurrence of this piece of code. I was thinking I could copy the code and put it into one of the registers and use the content of register to perform the matching. The text can have any of the special characters and while matching, it needs to be treated as ordinary text. Is it possible to match using the register content? in what other way I can accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Plugin

This becomes even easier by selecting the lines, and then searching for the visual selection, and you don't clobber a register through this. There are several plugins that extend the built-in normal mode `*` command to visual mode, also my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

#### Manually

If you want to do this manually, through a register, use a *very nomagic* (`\V`) pattern, and escape the special characters. To insert the (escaped) register contents into the command-line, insert register `<C-R>` with the expression register is used:

```
/\V<C-R>=substitute(escape(@@, '/\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I do not own the computer i am working on so I cannot install any plugins. Is there any way I can do this with just basic Vim?

Comment: Note that as long as you can place any files on the computer, you can have Vim plugins, too. By adding to the `'runtimepath'` option, you can include arbitrary plugin directories, also from USB drives etc.

Comment: Thanks again. If it is not too much to ask, could you please explain the expression you have written. I am unable to follow it.

Comment: +1 very nice usage `\V` and `@@`. I was thinking how to escape those chars, and forgot the `\V`... @Gautam, don't forget to vote useful answers up..

Comment: @IngoKarkat I have a question regarding the `@@` usage. I knew that `@@` can re-**execute** the content of a last register. I often use it for replaying macros. also checked the `:h @r`, it says `@@` can get the content of unamed reg, the `@"`, I did some test, `@@` can get the content of last updated reg, no matter it was unnamed or named. can you pls tell where can I find this explanation in vim's help doc? regarding the explanation in `:h @r` doc for the `@@`, this could be a bug? Thank you.

Comment: @Kent: `@@` is just an alias for `@"`; they're 100% equivalent. What you're describing is just the normal behavior of the default register.

Comment: @Gautam: I've added some more explanation. You can `:help <topic>` for further details.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I found the problem, tested in this way: I have two lines in buf: `1111` and `2222`, now I am on `1111`, do `Y`, check `:reg` everything is fine. (only `@"` is `1111`)  then on `2222` do `"xY`, check `:reg`, `"x is 2222` and `"" is 2222` too... tested with `-u NONE`, vim 7.4.214. can you reproduce it there?

Comment: @Kent That's the expected behavior, isn't it?! `:h quotequote` says: This is like the unnamed register is pointing to the last used register.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I just re-checked the `:h registers`, and you are right, there it says `@"` will be filled regardless whether or not a named reg was used. But I remembered that it wasn't like that... I ever used `"xY` but kept the `@"` with old value.... what's wrong with me... :-(